# Query works fine in psql , but Django cursor.execute() gives "cannot extract elements from a scalar"

Tags: python, jquery, django, postgresql, scalar

I've got a large query which I need to run manually on a postgres DB from within Django. When I run the query manually in psql I have no problems, but when I run it using `cursor.execute()` in Python I get an error.

I reduced the query to the following:

```
select id from mytable, jsonb_array_elements(details) as detail_elements;
```

As you can see the second part takes some info from a jsonb field with which I do more in the larger query. This simple query runs great in psql (just showing a list of ids), so I then tried from within Django:

```
from django.db import connection
with connection.cursor() as cursor:
    cursor.execute("select id from mytable, jsonb_array_elements(details) as detail_elements;")
    rows = cursor.fetchall()
```

but I get this error:

```
psycopg2.errors.InvalidParameterValue: cannot extract elements from a scalar
```

Does anybody know what magic Django tries to do which makes it different from running this directly in psql?

I'm running Postgres 12.2 and Django 3.0.9 on Ubuntu 20.04.

Comment: which pg version do you use

Comment: @iklinac - I'm running Postgres 12.2. I also added it to the question.

Comment: jsonb_array_elements returns scalar for you so you would need to something similar to this answer here 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39236893/extract-json-array-from-postgres-table-gives-error-cannot-extract-elements-from

Comment: @iklinac - Thanks for the suggestion, but that seems to be talking about raw queries that are not working. My raw query works perfectly though. It's just that Django seems to be choking on it. Would you have any other ideas?